# Synaptic Package Manager is unable to load package indexes after update

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 64-bit

I found it interesting that an update/upgrade broke the ability of the Synaptic Package Manager to update from the archives. I do not know what information may be helpful:

Ubuntu 14.04 / AMD 64

Comment: It would seem that someone noticed this entry and fixed the problem. Synaptic is now working normally.